# How to reshape a data set based on aggregating on one column with specific conditions?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, data.table

My data set is based on disease counts. Many of the variables are categorical such as WeekSeries, MonthSeries and YearSeries. These labels refer to what week, month and year the disease count belongs to in my time series data.

The problem I am facing is building another data table that will sum the counts based on WeekSeries, MonthSeries and YearSeries. I need my method to make decisions as to whether WeekSeries 1 will be coded as `TS1 =1` or `TS2=1`. For example, in the original data you can see that that third observation doesn't fall in `TS1` but in `TS2` and because it falls in `TS2` it has `HolidaysPerSeason=10` as well.

I would like the method to decide that if the majority of the observations in WeekSeries 1 belong to `TS1=1` and `HolidaysPerSeason =11` then that will  be the final categories for `WeekSeries=1`.

### Original data

```
 WeekSeries  Counts  TS1  TS2  TS3  TS4  TS5  TS6  HolidaysPerSeason
     1         0      1    0    0    0    0    0          11
     1         1      1    0    0    0    0    0          11
     1         1      0    1    0    0    0    0          10
```

### Ideal Format

```
WeekSeries  Counts  TS1  TS2  TS3  TS4  TS5  TS6  HolidaysPerSeason
     1        2      1    0    0    0    0    0          11
```

This format is necessary for building regression models and other analysis.

This is fake data that resembles my real data:

```
    # a couple of the variables within my data
    JulianDate<-c(10985, 10986,10987)
    DateRcd<-c(NA,NA,"2000-01-31")
    Counts<-c(0,1,1)
    Day<-c("Sat","Sun","Mon")
    Weekend<-c(1,1,0)
    Season<-c(1,1,2)
    HolidaysPerSeason<-c(11,11,10)
    TS1<-c(1,1,0)
    TS2<-c(0,0,1)
    TS3<-c(0,0,0)
    TS4<-c(0,0,0)
    TS5<-c(0,0,0)
    TS6<-c(0,0,0)
    WeekSeries<-c(1,1,1)
    YearSeries<-c(1,1,1)
    MonthSeries<-c(1,1,1)
    mydata<-data.table(JulianDate,DateRcd,Counts,Day,Weekend,Season,HolidaysPerSeason, TS1,TS2,TS3,TS4,TS5,TS6,YearSeries,MonthSeries,WeekSeries) #data simulation
```

I tried using `data.table()` functions to aggregate based on WeekSeries and then merge it with the original data to build my ideal format for analysis.

### My closest to success attempt

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(mydata)
mydata1<-DT[, by = list(WeekSeries)] #doesn't work
mydata2<-DT[,sum(CountsofCholera), by=WeekSeries] #loses all the other variables
idealdata<-merge(mydata2,mydata,by.x=mydata2$WeekSeries) #attempts to regain  the lost variable, this doesn't work because the datasets are not the same length
```

What can I do to regain the other categorical variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be optimized in a few spots, but should give you the basic idea:

```
# sum up counts and count number of rows with identical values for the last several columns
DT[, .(Count = sum(Counts), .N), by = c(tail(names(DT), -4))][
   # assign same count number = total count to each row within same WeekSeries
   , Count := sum(Count), by = WeekSeries][
   # extract most frequent row (i.e. one with largest N, computed in line 1)
   , .SD[which.max(N)], by = WeekSeries]
#   WeekSeries Weekend Season HolidaysPerSeason TS1 TS2 TS3 TS4 TS5 TS6 YearSeries MonthSeries Count N
#1:          1       1      1                11   1   0   0   0   0   0          1           1     2 2
```

Comment: Your answer works for my test data set but when I translate it to my larger dataset I lose TS1 and TS2.  Could you add comments to your code so that I can try to figure out what to tweak?

Comment: @eddie Tweaking this part` by = c(tail(names(DT), -2))]`  from -4 to -2 worked but I don't know why. If you could explain or point out where  you found the solution that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Your solution does work. I'm not sure what the N is though. For an hour I thought it was the total number of counts for that week.

Comment: @Meli the first "by" picks the columns that you're interested in checking identical rows in (so adjusting that to suit your needs makes sense), and `.N` counts the number of rows for each such grouping of those columns. The name of that count column (automatically) is "N".

Comment: How about the .SD? Could you make your explanation more explicit please? How it works the whole `[  ]` `[  ]` `[  ]` with different things inside that get me what I want? A breakdown would be much appreciated!

Comment: I added some explanation of what each line does.

Answer (score 0):

Is group_by what you are looking for? For example, something like this?
You should have `dplyr`and `data.table` installed.

`mydata_new <- mydata %>% group_by(WeekSeries, TS1, HolidaysPerSeason) %>% summarise(count = n())`

Comment: Your solution created extra observations when I applied it to my larger data set. There should be 583 observations but your solution and eddi's  both created over 5000 observations.